# please give the command in Robocopy i should use to copy the files from primary server to the secondary server

Tags: robocopy

I got the command in robocopy as mentioned below

ROBOCOPY Source Destination [file…[file]…..] [Options]

Source: Source Directory 
Destination: Destination Directory 
Files: files to copy .

Please let us know what does the "\server\share\path" means? Kindly provide me an example on this command syntax and explain

Comment: Isn't this more of a server administration question? There's a separate site for such questions, serverfault.com.

Comment: Not necessary. I'm using robocopy to backup my SVN repository, so it is also programming related ;-)

Answer (score 9):

An example of a ROBOCOPY call would be

```
ROBOCOPY  C:\Users \\SERVER\backup\Users /MIR /R:0 /W:0
```

This copys everything under `C:\Users` to a network share at the UNC path `\\SERVER\backup`. If you don't know, what that means, [google for 'UNC path'](http://www.google.com/search?q=unc+path) or find a nice tutorial that explains how to setup network shares under Windows.

Instead of `\\SERVER\backup`, that copies to a remote machine, you are totally free to use something like `H:\` to copy to a local drive like a USB mass storage device.

The part `/MIR /R:0 /W:0` are *options* of ROBOCOPY. Call `ROBOCOPY /?` to get an explanation for these.

Cheers,